# Difference between DSP system toolbox and signal processing toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, toolbox

I come up with a question when studying MATLAB for signal processing purposes.
What is the difference between DSP system toolbox and signal processing toolbox in MATLAB.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you found an answer useful, upvote it. If a reply solved your problem or answered your question, please consider marking it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From mathworks.com:

**DSP System Toolbox™** provides algorithms, filters, design tools, and an app for processing streaming signals in MATLAB® and Simulink®. These capabilities are provided as MATLAB functions, MATLAB System objects™, and Simulink blocks. You can create and test systems for audio, communications, medical, and other real-time signal processing and IoT applications.

**Signal Processing Toolbox™** provides functions and apps to generate, measure, transform, filter, and visualize signals. The toolbox includes algorithms for resampling, smoothing, and synchronizing signals, designing and analyzing filters, estimating power spectra, and measuring peaks, bandwidth, and distortion. The toolbox also includes parametric and linear predictive modeling algorithms. You can use Signal Processing Toolbox to analyze and compare signals in time, frequency, and time-frequency domains, identify patterns and trends, extract features, and develop and validate custom algorithms to gain insight into your data.

**tl;dr:** The DSP system toolbox allows you to model complex systems for signal processing. It uses methods that are provided by the signal processing toolbox, but provides the means for the modelling of more complex, interconnected DSP systems.